# Faking a hardwood floor or flat surface in a carpeted office

Tags: flooring

My office chair is on a thin plastic office mat with cleats on top of thin shag carpeting but i find the chair rolls around and that mat constantly moves. it drives me crazy. What can I put on top of the carpet for the same feel as a hardwood floor so I can enjoy sitting at my desk again?

Comment: Chairmats are not all created equal.  You just need a better thicker one, with carpet cleats.

Comment: updated description, but yes it has cleats

Comment: Again, Chairmats are not all created equal.  You just need a better thicker one, with better carpet cleats.  I've "been there/done that".   "Thin" is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Buy another chair mat. It sounds like you have smooth bottomed one that is designed for use on a tile, concrete or wooden floor.

There are other chair mats that have short bumpy things on the bottom that grab into the carpet to keep it from moving around. They look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks, i should have specified this is what i already have and its not working out

Answer (score 1):

Buy a new carpet chair mat, but one labeled "high pile" which will have longer teeth on the bottom. To measure the length that you need, straighten a paperclip, and poke it through the carpet and pad down to the wood or concrete subfloor. Measure that distance from the tip of the paperclip to the top of the carpet fibers and purchase a high pile carpet chair mat that best matches that dimension.

The cheapest chair mats are marketed towards commercial use with thin carpeting that is directly glued to the subfloor, while home offices and nice commercial spaces will have additional foam padding under the carpet for comfort, but that extra foam makes it harder for the carpet mat with small teeth to hold its' position, so they make more expensive ones with longer teeth to work for carpet with foam padding that is thicker.